# How can a payment on a $62,000 Jaguar be $499 a month?

Tags: car, auto-loan, financing

I was in the mall today and some dealer had a $62,000 Jaguar on display which had $499 painted on the winshield, which I assume is a monthly payment.

If we ignore interest, that would be 500 x 12 = 6000 per year. So, it would be 10 years just to get to $60,000, forget about interest.

At 5% interest it would take 15 years to pay back a $62,000 loan at $500 a month.

So, what is going on here? Do people seriously take 15 year loans on cars now?

Comment: Might that have been for a lease rather than purchase?

Comment: Have you considered that it might have been a biweekly payment? That makes the maths a lot more reasonable.

Comment: Jaguar USA lists $489 lease for 36 months with ~$5000 down. One restriction is that mileage over 30k will be charged at $0.30/mile. They state a car starting at around $54k will be worth $30 at the end of the lease (you can buy it then). (No link because it will outdate quickly)

Answer (score 1):

It would be because of a sizable trade in/down payment, uk has an average of 11%, but you can put down more and still get a credit agreement on the rest.  I imagine quoted figure could be at the maximum down payment to give the smallest possible monthly amount as a marketing ploy.